# How to empty the cells of a DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've found questions similar on SO already, all over the net actually. Though I haven't found a working answer yet.

So I'm working in a windows form application using Visual studio 2008. Language is C#

I have a DataGridView that is **not** bound to a DataSource.

so:

```
MyDataGridView.DataSource = null;
```

wont work...

I've also tried

```
MyDataGridView.Rows.Clear();
```

But this removes all my custom made rows.

So I'm now looking for a way to just empty the contents of all cells (not including header cells). So it shouldn't affect anything else but the contents of the cells itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out how to do it myself, I simply loop trough the table, clearing every cell I encounter.

note: "dgUsers" is the name of my DataGridView

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgUsers.Columns.Count ;i++ )
      {
          for (int j = 0; j < dgUsers.Rows.Count; j++)
          {
               dgUsers.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value = "";
          }
      }
```

I bet there is a better way to do this and this might look a bit sloppy but it does the job. Yet I'd like to hear a better solution that clears the data.

Comment: This is probably the best way to do it if your rows aren't actually bound to anything.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyDataGridView.Columns.Count ;i++ )
  {
      for (int j = 0; j < MyDataGridView.Rows.Count; j++)
      {
           MyDataGridView.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value = DBNull.Value;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Add some explanation

Comment: `MyDataGridView.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value = null;` is more like it. Do not use DBNull.Value unless it is in reference to a database field.

Answer (score 0):

the code by pieter888 didnt worked for me the code i figured out was

```
int cnt=dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[0]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that using LINQ you can make it cleaner, specially with implicit types:

```
    foreach (var cell in from DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows from DataGridViewCell cell 
    in row.Cells select cell){
        cell.Value = string.Empty;
     }
```

Answer (score -2):

you can clear the entire grid by using

```
gridviewname.columns.clear();
```